# buscar palabras en múltiple campos y tablas con espacios laravel php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel

tengo el siguiente problema en laravel, no puedo buscar mas de 2 palabras con espacio (por ejmp. nombre categoria y nombre marca) en el "search del data table".

1. En esta imagen busco solo por categoria 'reloj'[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. En esta segunda imagen busco escribiendo 'reloj invicta' el resultado es 0.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Este es el codigo en el controller.

   ```
        $search = $request->input('search.value'); 
        $products =  Product::select('products.*')
                    ->with('category', 'brand', 'unit')
                    ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->leftjoin('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                    ->where([
                        ['products.name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%"],
                        ['products.is_active', true]
                    ])
                    ->orWhere([
                        ['products.code', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%"],
                        ['products.is_active', true]
                    ])
                    ->orWhere([
                        ['categories.name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%"],
                        ['categories.is_active', true],
                        ['products.is_active', true]
                    ])
                    ->orWhere([
                        ['brands.title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%"],
                        ['brands.is_active', true],
                        ['products.is_active', true]
                    ])
                    ->offset($start)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->orderBy($order,$dir)->get();
   ```

Comment: Cuando mencionas data table, te refieres a https://datatables.net ? Como inicializas la tabla en la vista?

Comment: No te funciona porque por ejemplo `'categories.name', 'LIKE', "%reloj invicta%" no se encontrara.

Comment: Estás haciendo búsqueda _por frase_, para hacerla _por palabras_ debes separarlas con `explode()` y agregar cada una al filtro. Desconozco cómo hacerlo en Laravel, de lo contrario, te ayudaría con una respuesta.